# Google App Engine Launcher delete datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a web application using Google AppEngine (GAE).
I have make some examples using dataStore (free, non-relational) using Google AppEngine Launcher (GAEL). All is correct. However I'd like delete the datastore before to deploy an application.
I have read that I have to use the command 
[--clear_datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?hl=es#Using_the_Datastore)
I don't know like running the server to delete the data store when I deploy or re-deploy the application.
I have chech some ways, for example I have write in the Application Settings(Edit==>Application Settings) in the GAEL some commands:

```
--clear_datastore
--clear_datastore /<ApplicationName>
--clear_datastore <ApplicationName>/
--clear_datastore <ApplicationName>
```

any idea?
Thank you.
Jose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clear_datastore` flag is only used to clear the development datastore which is running on your local machine with the dev_appserver. If you want to clear this development datastore, then when you run the dev appserver you can use the flags:

```
dev_appserver.sh --clear_datastore=yes <ApplicationName>
```

An important thing to note is that this **only** clears the development datastore. The development datastore does not get uploaded when you deploy the application. So you shouldn't be worried about clearing the local datastore before deploying the application.

If you want to delete entities that are already in your production server (running on App Engine), then you cannot do this from the command line using `dev_appserver.sh`. You can do this using the Datastore Admin tool in the AppEngine console. You can follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk) to bulk delete data. An important note is that you have to enable the Datastore Admin tool first by following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Enable_datastore_admin).